# laravel ajax request params yields null

Tags: php, ajax, laravel

I am new to laravel framework and started following the laravel tasks tutorial.
I am trying to pass via ajax request the name of the task in order to save it in the database.

**front end:**

```
var taskdata= {
    "name": $("#new_task").val()
};

//console.log(JSON.stringify(taskdata));

$.ajax({
    url: '/task',
    type: 'POST',
    data: taskdata,
    contentType: 'json',
    processData: false,
    success: function(result) {
        alert("success");
    }
});
```

**server side:**

```
Route::post('/task', function (Request $request) {

    //die(var_dump($request->json("name")));

    $validator = Validator::make(json_decode($request->getContent(), true), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return redirect('/')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validator);
    }

    $task = new \App\Task;
    $task->name = $request->name;
    $task->save();

    return redirect('/');
});
```

Comment: You can not access those values as you would “normal” form parameters - because you are sending JSON. Why are you sending JSON in the first place?

Comment: thought it would be the best practice what do you suggest instead?

Comment: Just send normal form data …? Or actually use the structure that you get after you decoded the JSON to access the data.

Comment: Remove `contentType`, and it will send the data the same way a normal form element would.

Comment: still yields null

Comment: It yields null because you are returning an `redirect` to the ajax. Instead return the error or the url

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better way to solve that:

```
Route::post('/task', function (Request $request) {
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);
    if ($validator->fails()) {
          throw new ValidationException($validator); //Your error handler should send JSON or redirect as appropriate.
    }

    $task = new \App\Task; 
    $task->name = $request->name;
    $task->save();

    if ($request->expectsJson()) {
        return response()->json(true); //Success
    } else {
        return redirect()->to("/");
    }
});
```

Update:

You also need to let jQuery process the data so it constructs a proper query:

```
var taskdata= {"name": $("#new_task").val()};
        //console.log(JSON.stringify(taskdata));
        $.ajax({
            url: '/task',
            type: 'POST',
            data: taskdata,
            contentType: 'json',
            processData: true, //Or remove it completely since the default is true
            success: function(result) {
                alert("success");
            }
        });
```

Comment: $request->all() still returning an empty array

Comment: What the content of your `taskdata` is will define what comes to the controller. You should ensure (maybe by doing console.log(taskdata)) that taskdata is actually having the expected value... You could just do `data : { name: taskdata}` if `taskdata` suppose to be the name you expect in the controller then...

Comment: taskdata contain the expected value

Comment: @user605505 you probably need to set `processData: true` in your ajax request. Unless your really want to send it as is.

Comment: you should write it as an answer instead of a comment since it fixed it!

Comment: @user605505 done. Sorry I'm all over the place today

Answer (score 1):

> When using the validate method during an AJAX request, Laravel will not generate a redirect response. Instead, Laravel generates a JSON response containing all of the validation errors. This JSON response will be sent with a 422 HTTP status code.

Hence you could change your controller method to

```
Route::post('/task', function (Request $request) {

    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
        'name' => 'required|max:255',
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails()) {
        return $validator->errors()->all();
    }

    $task = new \App\Task; 
    $task->name = $request->name;
    $task->save();

    return url("/");
});
```

and your ajax method as

```
var taskdata= {
    "name": $("#new_task").val(),
    "_token" : "{{ csrf_token() }}"
};

$.ajax({
    url: '/task',
    type: 'POST',
    data: taskdata,
    contentType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        console.log(result); // The url
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data.responseJSON); // Here you could see the error
    }
});
```

Comment: my main concern is that $request->all() returns an empty array

Comment: As advised by @apokryfos you could remove `processData: false,` or set `processData: true,`

Comment: If the validator fails you should return a response with an error http code e.g. `return response()->json($validator->errors()->all(),422)` . That's the only way you can get the `error` function to run.

Comment: Won't the response be by default an 422, if the request type is ajax?